# When if-clause is removable in second conditional sentences?

Tags: conditional-constructions

I know that if a second conditional sentence is about an advise we can remove if-clause. for example:

- If I were you, I would by a new phone -> I would buy a new phone

but what about hypotheticals and desires. for example it is possible to remove if-clause in below sentences?

- If I were rich, I would buy a big house.
- If I eat everything, I would get fat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, where the condition is implied or understood, there is no need for an IF clause.

You could ask me "Have you ever thought about what you'd do if you won the lottery?" and I might reply "I would buy a big house."

However, in some cases the condition can be understood without an IF sentence even having occurred earlier in the conversation.

For example, imagine a dinner at which you offer me additional food and I shake my head, saying "I would get fat."